# Next-auth token bearer authorization

Tags: javascript

I was creating my own jwt, but I started using next-auth, so it generated one automatically and I stopped creating my own, as there was no need.
The problem is that this generated token does not work to pass as authorization for a post. What could I do?

this is the code for creating a context in the database, in the headers, I am passing a Bearer ${token}, which has the information of a jwt automatically generated by next-auth, but as said, it does not work.

```
const token = Cookie.get('next-auth.session-token')

async function createContent(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault()

    try {
      const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
  
      const contentBody = await api.post('/content', {
        content: formData.get('content'),
      }, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
      setClicked(true);
      setId(contentBody.data.contentCreated.id)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erro ao criar conteúdo:", error);
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: just use console.log(token) and try to check it's validity through [jwt.io](http://jwt.io)

Comment: I tested, and the token generated by next-auth is not a valid signature

Comment: so you need to check the method you're using to generate jwt access token and correct it